# cluster mode zookeeper.properties and log4j.properties file not reading

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, apache-storm

Currently i have cluster looks zoo keeper 2 node,Kafka 3 node ,storm 3 node.
My topology I have configured zookeeper's using property file loader i have loaded zookeeper ip/ports local mode working but cluster mode not working.

My maven project structure is

project

- src/main/java
- src/main/test
- src/main/resources

inside of resource dir i have a file's zoo.config and log4j.config
My topology is

```
public class Mytopology  {   public static void main(String[] args) throws AlreadyAliveException,
        InvalidTopologyException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
/** PropertiesConfigurator is used to configure logger from properties file */   
    Properties prop = new Properties();   
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("src/main/resources/log4j.properties");           
    String zoo_cluster=null;
    int zoo_cluster_timeout_ms;
    /** Topology definition */
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();   
    builder.setSpout("kafka", new KafkaSpout(),1);
    builder.setBolt("bolt1",new bolt1(),1).shuffleGrouping("kafka");
    builder.setBolt("bolt2",new bolt2(),1).shuffleGrouping("bolt1");

    /** create a storm Config object*/
    Config config = new Config();            
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/zookeeper-config.properties"));       
    zoo_cluster= prop.getProperty("zookeeper.connect");   
    String zoo_cluster_timeout= prop.getProperty("consumer.timeout.ms");   
    zoo_cluster_timeout_ms=Integer.parseInt(zoo_cluster_timeout);
    config.put("kafka.zookeeper.connect",zoo_cluster);
    config.put("kafka.consumer.timeout.ms",zoo_cluster_timeout_ms);
  /** submit topology into cluster */
    if (args != null && args.length > 2) {                       
        StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[2], config,builder.createTopology());
        System.out.println("Topology submitted into Storm Cluster ........");
    }
    /** submit topology into local */
    else if(args != null && args.length > 1) {
          LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
        cluster.submitTopology("storm-local", config,
                builder.createTopology());
        System.out.println("Topology submitted into Local Mode........");
        Utils.sleep(100000);
    }

}
```

}

Plz help me! how read property file in cluster mode both zookeeper config and error logs

Comment: it's unclear which component is unable to read zk/log4j configs. Kafka? Storm?

Comment: Storm topology i am configuring zookeeper's config.put("kafka.zookeeper.connect",zoo_cluster);